# WPF dynamic binding to property

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, itemscontrol

I have an ItemsControl that should display the values of some properties of an object.

The ItemsSource of the ItemsControl is an object with two properties: **Instance** and **PropertyName**.

What I am trying to do is displaying all the property values of the *Instance* object, but I do not find a way to set the Path of the binding to the *PropertyName* value:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource={Binding Path=InstanceProperties}>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=PropertyName, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                <TextBlock Text=": "/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Source=??{Binding Path=Instance}??, Path=??PropertyName??, Mode=OneWay}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

the question marks are the points where I don't know how to create the binding.

I initially tried with a MultiValueConverter:

```
<TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding}">
    <TextBlock.DataContext>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource getPropertyValue}">
            <Binding Path="Instance" Mode="OneWay"/>
            <Binding Path="PropertyName" Mode="OneWay"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.DataContext>
</TextBlock>
```

The MultiValueConverter uses Reflection to look through the *Instance* and returns the value of the property.

But if the property value changes, this change is not notified and the displayed value remains unchanged.

I am looking for a way to do it with XAML only, if possible, if not I will have to write a wrapper class to for the items of the ItemsSource collection, and I know how to do it, but, since it will be a recurring task in my project, it will be quite expensive.

### Edit:

For those who asked, **InstanceProperties** is a property on the ViewModel which exposes a collection of objects like this:

```
public class InstanceProperty : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    //[.... INotifyPropertyChanged implementation ....]

    public INotifyPropertyChanged Instance { get; set; }

    public string PropertyName { get; set; }

}
```

Obviously the two properties notify theirs value is changing through INotifyPropertyChanged, I don't include the OnPropertyChanged event handling for simplicity.

The collection is populated with a limited set of properties which I must present to the user, and I can't use a PropertyGrid because I need to filter the properties that I have to show, and these properties must be presented in a graphically richer way.

Thanks

Comment: Please show the ViewModel/CodeBehind to let us see, how your datastructure is

Comment: I cannot think of any way to dynamically iterate and bind to an arbitrary object's properties in XAML only. You need to write a VM or behaviour to do this so you can watch for change notifications, but do it in a generic way using reflection you can just reuse it throughout your project.

Comment: You aren't looking for a [PropertyGrid](https://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=PropertyGrid&referringTitle=Home)?

Comment: I edited the post to provide the informations you asked, thanks for the comments btw

Comment: @GazTheDestroyer thanks for the advice, I can modify the InstanceProperty class to provide also a "Value" property and receive value changes notification through INotifyPropertyChanged, if you would like to answer I can mark your post as accepted answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, thanks to @GazTheDestroyer comment:

> **@GazTheDestroyer** wrote: I cannot think of any way to dynamically iterate and bind to an arbitrary object's properties in XAML only. You need to write a VM or behaviour to do this so you can watch for change notifications, but do it in a generic way using reflection you can just reuse it throughout your project

I found a solution: editing the ViewModel class **InstanceProperty** like this

1. added a **PropertyValue** property
2. listen to PropertyChanged event on **Instance** and when the **PropertyName** value changed is fired, raise PropertyChanged on **PropertyValue**
3. When **Instance** or **PropertyName** changes, save a reference to Reflection's PropertyInfo that will be used by **PropertyValue** to read the value

here is the new, complete, ViewModel class:

```
public class InstanceProperty : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    #region Properties and events

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private INotifyPropertyChanged FInstance = null;
    public INotifyPropertyChanged Instance
    {
        get { return this.FInstance; }
        set
        {
            if (this.FInstance != null) this.FInstance.PropertyChanged -= Instance_PropertyChanged;
            this.FInstance = value;
            if (this.FInstance != null) this.FInstance.PropertyChanged += Instance_PropertyChanged;
            this.CheckProperty();
        }
    }

    private string FPropertyName = null;
    public string PropertyName
    {
        get { return this.FPropertyName; }
        set
        {
            this.FPropertyName = value;
            this.CheckProperty();
        }
    }

    private System.Reflection.PropertyInfo Property = null;

    public object PropertyValue
    {
        get { return this.Property?.GetValue(this.Instance, null); }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Private methods

    private void CheckProperty()
    {
        if (this.Instance == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.PropertyName))
        {
            this.Property = null;
        }
        else
        {
            this.Property = this.Instance.GetType().GetProperty(this.PropertyName);
        }
        this.RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(PropertyValue));
    }

    private void Instance_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == this.PropertyName)
        {
            this.RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(PropertyValue));
        }
    }

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyname)
    {
        this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyname));
    }

    #endregion

}
```

and here is the XAML:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource={Binding Path=InstanceProperties}>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=PropertyName, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                <TextBlock Text=": "/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=PropertyValue, Mode=OneWay}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```